# Avalição de email

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com um problema para analisar o email num `form` de cadastro, o que eu gostaria de fazer é que assim que o usuario inserir seu email no campo `email`, o site já avalie o email no banco de dados para saber se ele está disponivel para realizar o cadastro. E caso contrario, informar abaixo que o email está indisponível.

Alguem saberia me dizer o processo para fazer isso?

Comment: E o que você já fez? Qual é sua dúvida específica?

Comment: O que eu consegui fazer para resolver o problema, foi usando um outro arquivo para validar o cadastro, que verifica se o email já existe no banco de dados via php, caso exista ele volta para a tela de cadastro. Mas eu estou procurando uma forma de poder avaliar o email assim que o usuario preencher o input email no form do cadastro, sem que ele precise clicar no botão "cadastrar" do form para chamar o arquivo que valida o cadastro.

Comment: @Vynstus, você está disposto a usar Jquery para esse fim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisei disso e desenvolvi:

jQuery:

```
var email = $("#usuario_email");
    email.blur(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/outras/verificaEmail.php",
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {"usuario_email": $("#usuario_email").val()},
            dataType: "json",       
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("usuario_email");
                console.log(data);
                $("#resposta").text(data.email);
            },
            error: function(a, b, c) {
                console.log(a);
                console.log(b);
                console.log(c); 
            }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">E-mail de Acesso</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usuario_email" name="usuario_email" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail">
    <div id='resposta'></div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
if(isset($_POST['usuario_email'])){

    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_POST['usuario_email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "outras");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cadastrousuarios WHERE usuario_email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuário cadastrado com este email.'));
    } else { 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Parabéns! Você poderá usar este e-mail como usuário.' ));
    }
}
```

Creio que seja a solução mais compatível no momento que eu saiba para te ajudar.